# How to do a loop SUM() amount?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am needing to do a loop that sums the next X rows until it reaches 
        Column_Key <> (X Row Column_Key) OR (X Row Key_2) NOT IN ('18', '19').

On the left I have Keys which are individual users. I think what I need to do is a loop for each unique Key; 93246499, 93246616, 93246697 and 93246831.
Each has a transcode associated with them:

```
Code 36 = Charge
Code18 = Paid
Code 15 & 31 = Waive
```

What I am wanting is for each instance of the 36 Code (Charge) to look at the next row (I'm currently using lead() for the Date Paid) and determine if the transcode is different. Here are the different scenarios:
In all of the examples below this is by Key if the Key is <> Row 1 Key then it stops at that step.

```
Row 1 Code 36 Row 2 Code 36 = Stop and count as UnPaid (this is already setup)
Row 1 Code 36 Row 2 Code 15, 31 = Set Waive Amount to the Late Amount (this is already setup).
```

**Row 1 Code 36 Row 2 Code 18, 19 = Continue searching next row until reaching Code 15, 31 or 36 and SUM the Late columns. IF we reach code 15 or 31 then set Waive amount to the Late amount.**
Once these are done I plan on doing `SELECT * FROM #TEST WHERE Trans_Code = 36` so that each 36 will have the respective fields picked out.

I have done this in a long exaggerated CASE Statement but it is missing some code to handle the different Loan_Key instances nor does it break if the Trans_Code is not in (18, 19) and just keeps adding them up.

```
SELECT *
      ,CASE WHEN LEAD([Loan Key], 1) OVER(PARTITION BY [Loan Key] ORDER BY [Date]) = [Loan Key] THEN 
            CASE WHEN LEAD(TRANS_CODE, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY [Loan Key] ORDER BY [Date]) IN ('18', '19') THEN [Amount Paid] + LEAD([NSF Charge], 1) OVER(PARTITION BY [Loan Key] ORDER BY [Date]) + ISNULL(
                 CASE WHEN LEAD([Loan Key], 2) OVER(PARTITION BY [Loan Key] ORDER BY [Date]) = [Loan Key] THEN
                      CASE WHEN LEAD(TRANS_CODE, 2) OVER(PARTITION BY [Loan Key] ORDER BY [Date]) IN ('18', '19') THEN LEAD([NSF Charge], 2) OVER(PARTITION BY [Loan Key] ORDER BY [Date]) + ISNULL(
                           CASE WHEN LEAD([Loan Key], 3) OVER(PARTITION BY [Loan Key] ORDER BY [Date]) = [Loan Key] THEN
                                CASE WHEN LEAD(TRANS_CODE, 3) OVER(PARTITION BY [Loan Key] ORDER BY [Date]) IN ('18', '19') THEN LEAD([NSF Charge], 3) OVER(PARTITION BY [Loan Key] ORDER BY [Date]) + ISNULL(
                                     CASE WHEN LEAD([Loan Key], 4) OVER(PARTITION BY [Loan Key] ORDER BY [Date]) = [Loan Key] THEN
                                          CASE WHEN LEAD(TRANS_CODE, 4) OVER(PARTITION BY [Loan Key] ORDER BY [Date]) IN ('18', '19') THEN LEAD([NSF Charge], 4) OVER(PARTITION BY [Loan Key] ORDER BY [Date])
                                               ELSE 0
                                           END
                                      END, 0)
                                     ELSE 0
                                 END
                            END, 0)
                           ELSE 0
                       END
                  END, 0)
                 ELSE 0 END
            ELSE 0
        END
  FROM #Test
 WHERE [Loan Key] = '93246916' --AND TRANS_CODE = '36'
```

Edit: I can't post images so here's a text example...
Example Data:

```
Key   Date         Code        Paid
1     10/1/2018     36          0
1     11/1/2018     18          1
1     11/30/2018    18          10
1     1/1/2019      19          20
1     5/1/2019      36          0
1     6/1/2019      36          10
1     7/1/2019      36          10
2     11/1/2018     36          0
2     1/1/2019      18          10
2     2/1/2019      36          0
2     3/1/2019      36          0
2     4/1/2019      36          0
2     5/1/2019      18          50
```

Expected Result:

Show only results for Code 36, Date is equal to the last Paid Date (Code 18 or 19)

```
Key    Date        Code       Paid
1      1/1/2019    36         31
1      5/1/2019    36         0
1      6/1/2019    36         10
1      7/1/2019    36         10
2      1/1/2019    36         10
2      2/1/2019    36         0
2      3/1/2019    36         0
2      5/1/2019    36         50
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are trying to do would very helpful.  It is unlikely that you need the construct you have created.

Comment: Sample data as text is MUCH preferred over images. Images really aren't very helpful. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Updated with what I'm assuming you mean as Text. This isn't a 1 to 1 comparison but I believe it should help me get to where I need.

Comment: Why does `2019-01-01` have a value of `36` for `code` in your expected results? In your sample it's `19`. Why is `2019-01-06` not in the expected results, when it does have a value of `36` for `code`?

Comment: Because for the output I want it to be equal to the LAST Paid Date before the next 36 code occurrence. "Expected Result:

Show only results for Code 36, Date is equal to the last Paid Date (Code 18 or 19)"     You'll see my other "dumb" case statement above. I'm trying to reduce this as well because it's just extremely bulky, difficult to read and seems like poor code to me.

Comment: That doesn't explain why `2019-01-06` isn't in your expected results

Comment: Oh your talking the 6/1/2019 then yes that should be there.