# Is there a way to reduce this case statement into something easier to read?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an extremely long CASE statement that is simply modifying the numbers in 3 different locations of the CASE. Is it possible to create some form of loop and reduce this code?

This goes on for 27 iterations so I reduced it to show only the first 5. Any help is appreciated!

```
SELECT [Loan Key]
      ,[Trans_Code]
      ,[Date]
      ,[NSF Charge]
      ,[Date Paid]
      ,[Amount Paid]
      ,CASE WHEN LEAD(TRANS_CODE, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY [Loan Key] ORDER BY [Date]) = '36' THEN [Amount Outstanding]
            WHEN LEAD([Loan Key], 2) OVER(PARTITION BY [Loan Key] ORDER BY [Date]) = LEAD([Loan Key], 1) OVER(PARTITION BY [Loan Key] ORDER BY [Date]) 
                  AND LEAD(TRANS_CODE, 2) OVER(PARTITION BY [Loan Key] ORDER BY [Date]) = '36' THEN LEAD([Amount Outstanding], 1) OVER(PARTITION BY [Loan Key] ORDER BY [Date])
            WHEN LEAD([Loan Key], 3) OVER(PARTITION BY [Loan Key] ORDER BY [Date]) = LEAD([Loan Key], 2) OVER(PARTITION BY [Loan Key] ORDER BY [Date]) 
                  AND LEAD(TRANS_CODE, 3) OVER(PARTITION BY [Loan Key] ORDER BY [Date]) = '36' THEN LEAD([Amount Outstanding], 2) OVER(PARTITION BY [Loan Key] ORDER BY [Date])
            WHEN LEAD([Loan Key], 4) OVER(PARTITION BY [Loan Key] ORDER BY [Date]) = LEAD([Loan Key], 1) OVER(PARTITION BY [Loan Key] ORDER BY [Date]) 
                  AND LEAD(TRANS_CODE, 4) OVER(PARTITION BY [Loan Key] ORDER BY [Date]) = '36' THEN LEAD([Amount Outstanding], 3) OVER(PARTITION BY [Loan Key] ORDER BY [Date])
            ELSE 0
        END AS [Amount Outstanding2]
      ,[Amount Waived]
  INTO #Summary4
  FROM #Summary3
WHERE [Loan Key] = '94523010'
```

Comment: `CASE` **Expression**, it's not a `Case` Statement; they don't exist in SQL Server.

Comment: Learned something new, thanks!

Comment: Are you simply trying to get the "last" value when for `TRANS_CODE` had a value of `36`?

Comment: Yes and no... each [Loan Key] has multiple Trans_Codes in random orders. My other code is doing cumulative sums on columns and I'm trying to line up the balance as of the 36 code. Example: Loan 1 has Trans_Code 36, 36, 18, 36, 18, 18, 18, 36. I would need to know the next Amount Outstanding as of the 36 code for each of those 4 instances.

Comment: The fact that you're going into a 4th temporary table object makes this "smell" like an XY Problem as well. Perhaps you would be better off (in a separate question) showing what you're original data looks like and your target results and your attempts so far. I very much doubt you need 4(+?) Temporary table to achieve that.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. As the user is new, I would be good if whomever did could comment to explain why; otherwise they won't learn how to post better questions. A downvote, without a reason why (which could also be upvoting an existing comment) is worthless to new users.

Comment: The multiple temp tables are just because I was breaking different small sections out as I've been doing it 1 step at a time. Probably not right but it seems easier to me. My original question is here if you care to look (I have all the data at this point just trying to clean up the code): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58770409/how-to-do-a-loop-sum-amount?noredirect=1#comment103827102_58770409

Answer (score 1):

Based on the logic you have, it would *seem* far easier to write the below:

```
SELECT S3.[Loan Key]
      ,S3.[Trans_Code]
      ,S3.[Date]
      ,S3.[NSF Charge]
      ,S3.[Date Paid]
      ,S3.[Amount Paid]
      ,TC.Amount Outstanding
FROM #Summary3 S3
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) ca.Amount Outstanding
                  FROM #Summary3 ca
                  WHERE S3.[Loan Key] = ca.[Loan Key]
                    AND ca.TRANS_CODE = 36
                  ORDER BY ca.[Date] DESC) TC
WHERE S3.[Loan Key] = '94523010'
```